# Mips Assembler- How to get the length of a .ascii

Tags: assembly, mips, assemblies, mips32, mips64

I am new in this community. We are programming mips in university, and I need a solution for my problem in my homework.
We have to open a .pgm file and read the so called header (in this case with p5 format and variable length x wide ). When you open the file which you had read you get 4 rows with 1st. p5; 2nd. length x wide; third the color depth and fourth long term of ascii code.
My job is it now to convert this ascii and I think I have to know the size of this ascii.
Previously, I had a mips code for converting ascii, but the problem here is, that this code converts just a part of my ascii term, like this (comments are in german- sorry for that):

```
.data
str:    .ascii "GV_]VTI=97:@JPH<1-/6;L\pz ­¶³¶»ÃËËÄ»°y{xzk`L@@?>9326<DD:1.--++*-./-//000002222344///35;@LVau ¥´¬§»ÇÄ¸³³»ª °¿ÅÃ¹±¯¦||x{{yttw{sv}¡°¸±¡¡£¢£p_Z[_hfYUW^accacdehhhhdghjjlnnonnnljifjgfdggfdiiiillllglrvtkiltzx~«ÀÖ¿°©´¾ÃÇÈ×ßãÖÇ»º­¡±¼ËÙENSOIHD>;>CHTPB4/+.6<JWizª¯®°¸ÃËËÄ»¶xvj\NECDB<735:?:40//---,+,--./00000222235400259=DNXdw£­®³½Á½³¯¯²¢¥§°»ÃÆÃµ©«}z{|xtmmqus¡±À¹¦m`ZZ^ce\WZ^abcacdehhhhdghjjlnnonnnlljijhggihhfiiiillmljnuxvnlqw~|¤¶ÐáÕÉÅÇÈÇÉÌÝàÒÄ¾³µª¡¡¤±¼ËÙBGIHB@??DILNRI=1,*-6=ISao §¨­·ÃËËÄ»º¯wpg\SIEDC>83359520110//.--,-//0000022224751139=CGOXfx£®¼¶®¨¤£¥°»À»¾¼³©¥vnjjmsz¬ÅÅÆ³xxttxuja[Y[_c`^]^abcacdfhhhhdghjjlnnnnnnonkjlkihjjhghhhhkkjknsy}vpqw~¸ÏãéáÝ×ÓÌÁÂÈÙàÂ¶²ª¬¥¦¢§ ¡¨±¼ÌÙ@DFKC?=@CFFA<82.+)-6>IO[e| £«´ÅËËÄ¼Á¹­vndbVKACA<632247322321011/.-.//000022225772/4<AFIQYhx¢°½­{¡±½½±²¶´®|lmos¸ÍÌ®tpmjgnnjc[XX[`a`_^abcacdfhjhhdghjjlnoonnnpomknmkjljihggggjjjjsv{wrs}¸ÑãíêÝß×ÏÇ¸´½ÐÛµ²§¡¨¡ª ¢«²¤¡«±ºÌÙ:ADEA>:5;94268501051"
# it converts just to: GV_]VTI=97:@JPH<1 
        .text
main:


addi $s0, $zero, 0  # $s0 :=0; hier wird das Ergebnis aufsummiert
la $s1,str          # $s1 := &str; hier wird der Zeiger auf das nächste Zeichen gehalten
addi $s2, $zero, 10 # $s2 := 10; hier steht konstand die 10 zur Multiplikaton
addi $s3, $zero, 48 # s3 := 48; hier 48, um die ASCII "0" in den Wert 0 umzuwandeln

loop:
lb $s4,($s1)        # Lade nächstes Zeichen des
sub $s4, $s4, $s3   #Bilde ASCII-Ziffer auf Integer-Wert [0..9] ab
bltz $s4,terminate  # Wenn Zeichen <0,
mult $s0, $s2
mflo $s0            # §s0 := §s0 *10
add $s0, $s0, $s4   # s0= s0 + Ziffernwert
addi $s1, $s1, 1    # s1= s1+1; also auf die nächstes Zeichn im String
j loop

terminate:
li $v0,1            # Resultat ausgeben
or $a0, $zero, $s0  # in ss0 stand das Ergebnis
syscall
li $v0,10
syscall
```

Hope you can give me a hint.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to convert. That is clearly not a number?

Answer (score 0):

At first I misunderstood your question, but I still think my sort of answer is also part of real answer, so first:

One question should be *"how to find end of header and start of image data"*.

Last char of [PGM header](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html#format) is "first whitespace character after maximum gray value". So you have to parse whole header value by value, until you parse the gray-max, then the next byte should be whitespace (`32` (space), `9` (TAB), `13` (CR), `10` (LF), `11` (VT), `12` (FF)), then pixel data starts.

IMHO that's quite stupid format, as I bet somebody in DOS did produce some image with "13, 10" CR+LF after gray max, but... not your problem (or check your file after loading into memory, what did it read).

And now back to your real question...

First thing, those data are not ASCII. They are binary pixel data. Your "GV" is already two pixels of values 71 and 86. When you display it as ASCII string, then of course 71 is shown as 'G', but that's not relevant in any way. Everything "ASCII" about PGM is only the header, after you detect end of header, the binary data pours in.

And the size of these binary data is `width*height*bytes_per_pixel`. `Bytes_per_pixel` is 1 for `gray_max < 256`, and 2 for `gray_max` being in 256..65535 range.

When 2 bytes per pixels are used, the most significant byte is first (so value `4097` is encoded as bytes: `16, 1` and value 71 is encoded as: `0, 71`).

If you have some 0-255 grayscale image with "max gray" in header set to 255, then you simply read the remaining `(width*height)` bytes of file as binary data (after the last header character), and that's it, those are your pixel data, row by row, from top to bottom.

If max_gray is something else, like 40, or 15000, then it's questionable, whether you should somehow convert the pixel data into 0-255 8 bit range (in first case "upscaling" them, in second "downscaling", probably by some gamma transformation if this would want to be professional PGM reader). But I expect your school task is only about 0-255 images without implementing gamma correction.